# Where can I find the information or documentation to allow a stripe connected account to add bank information within my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, stripe-payments

I have been looking for documentation or tutorials which show what to do in order to allow a creator (who already has a connect account (it was created when he first authenticated)) to add the banking information necessary for him to withdraw funds from his connect account (transfer his funds).

How app works:

- Creator makes an account like on patreon.
- User subscribes to creator like on patreon.

**How can I allow the ***express* connected account** add his details?**

Here are some links I have gatherd but don't seem to contain info on how to:

- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts
- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of Account.

Standard Accounts: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#create-link

Express Accounts: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-link

Custom Accounts: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding

[For express accounts redirect users to stripes onboarding](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide)

Answer (score 1):

**I emailed them for info before I got this answer. I will include their info here:**

I understand you would like to know how a user can input their bank account information on the client-side.

As per in [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts) Stripe will handle onboarding, account management, and identity verification for your platform, which means you can [onboard users very quickly](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide). This is done by using the OAuth connection flow, after this, your user will be able to [connect to your platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-express-accounts).

You can test this by trying the sample we have using [Rocket Rides](https://rocketrides.io/). Also, here you will be able to find the [demo’s source code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides).

On the other hand, if you are referring to updating this information after the onboarding, this is done by logging on the Express Dashboard, and you can achieve this by integrating with the [Express Dashboard](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-dashboard).

---

Extra info: https://stripe.com/connect/express

This is especially helpful: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide